# error "Macros is not available in this workbook or all macro may be disabled

Tags: vba, excel

I have developed an customized ribbon in excel and some macros using Visual Basics Script. Also, after completing when I send my excel to another computer along with add-ins I am getting error "Macros is not available in this workbook or macro may be disabled. Please be noted that I created add-ins and added the add-ins too but still I am getting this error. Kindly help me with this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Where's the code?

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, go to `File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Macro Settings` and select an appropriate setting to use.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from what CLR wrote (and using the Excel file in the xlsm format), I noticed that if I run this VBS in a batch mode, it only gives me results if the batch is run "as an Administrator".