# Cannot run the macro. "The macro may not be available or all macros may be disabled"

Tags: vba

This topic has been already mentioned, however without a solution. I have a very simple Macro calling other workbooks and their macros to execute:

```
Sub Execute()

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:Beta.xlsm"
Application.Run "C:Beta.xlsm!Macro"

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:Alpha.xlsm"
Application.Run "C:Alpha.xlsm!Macro1"

ThisWorkbook.SaveChanges = False

Application.Quit

End Sub
```

The problem is that, now I receive an `error 1004` with a message: `Cannot run the macro The macro may not be available or all macros may be disabled.`

PS. I have already enabled Macros and ticked the box in Trust Centre (still having error).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error "Macros is not available in this workbook or all macro may be disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42297866/error-macros-is-not-available-in-this-workbook-or-all-macro-may-be-disabled)

Comment: @Sami it is not a duplicate and please read (WITH UNDERSTANDING) what I have asked and done up to date and then compare against this alleged "duplicate".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reinstalled the entire MS Office package. Now it works. I have no idea what caused this issue. There was no other solution to it. I have applied everything that has been mentioned in this and other posts. Thanks for ur time tho.

Answer (score 1):

on the ribbon click DEVELOPER --> Macro Security (yellow triangle with exclamation mark)--> Macro Setting --> Enable all macros.

Comment: Macros are already enabled because the `execute()` macro is throwing the error.

Comment: I have already done it MarcinSzaleniec and it has been mentioned in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that module name and sub name are not the same.
In other words module name must have a different name respect the sub name.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specify the full path to the .xlsm files (here in C:\temp) otherwise current directory is used.

To run the macro, remove the path (only xlsm file name)

```
Sub Execute()

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Temp\Beta.xlsm"
    Application.Run "Beta.xlsm!Macro"

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Temp\Alpha.xlsm"
    Application.Run "Alpha.xlsm!Macro1"

    ThisWorkbook.SaveChanges = False

    Application.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. There is even more errors now.

Comment: Now it tells me that "Sorry, we couldn't find the file. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?"

Comment: You should modify the c:\temp I used in the example. Where are your alpha and beta.xlsm files