# "Cannot run the macro (...). The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help regarding the "Cannot run the macro (...). The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.". I have tried the most common suggestions like enabling macros & compiling the project but it does not help.

Short introduction:

I have created a macro which for years run succesfully (let's call it old version) but recently the company upgraded to Office 2016 Professional Plus and it started giving "Subscript out of range error". I have verified and corrected the macro - the reason was quite trivial: new versions of excel create 1 sheet in new workbook while the older ones created 3. The macro tried to do an action in a non existing sheet.

I have saved the changes and sent the macro for testing (new version).

The macro runs at Workbook.Open by showing a simple form, but new version does not show the form on client's computer. Simply nothing happens. I have added a command button, which starts the macro and sent it for testing, but after pressing the button there is again a "Cannot run the macro" message. I thought thet maybe there is an error in the code but after compiling and double checking everything on my PC I could not find any errors. So I have created a new workbook from the scratch with a single line macro:

```
Sub test() 
MsgBox "macros enabled"
End Sub
```

To my surprise running this macro on client's computer also returns the same error message. At this point I thought that there are some security settings that prevent running the macros but a) the old version of the macro is working, b) I have asked the client to download some free example macro from the net and it also works.

Just to add: the new version of the macro (and obviously the MsgBox macro) is working fine on my home PC (Office 2013), my work laptop (Office 2019) and my wife's work laptop (Office 365). The problem is only on client's machine.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**TL:DR** Macro is working on Office 2019, 2013 and 365 but returns error on Clients Office 2016.

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-or-disable-macros-in-office-files-12b036fd-d140-4e74-b45e-16fed1a7e5c6 and if the Excel file with the macro in it is somehow downloaded from the internet or other unsecure zone you might need to ask the customer to first [unblock](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/delay/p/unblockingdownloadedfile/) the file.

Comment: Thanks, but the macros are enabled and the one from the net is working fine. The ones I share dont.

Comment: So your customer did unblock the xlsm file? Do they happen to run an antivirus that is overzealous?

Comment: Sounds like the client's Office install might need to be repaired. Are they running only one version of Office? Or are they e.g. running 2016 but then later installed Access 2010?

Comment: You're not the only user with this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389562/cannot-run-the-macro-the-macro-may-not-be-available-in-this-workbook and there is one that did a re-install https://stackoverflow.com/a/48531332/578411 so if you're out of options I'm afraid that will be your only route.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on "new versions of excel create 1 sheet in new workbook while the older ones created 3".  This is a ***user setting*** - my new workbooks have been set to 1 worksheet for as long as I remember.

Comment: @rene that +10 answer (now +9) is terrible, unjustified advice. Popping a `MsgBox` doesn't require enabling VBA code to write & modify VBA code as it's running. Don't tick that checkbox unless you're *actually* doing meta-prorgamming in VBA, or need to run code that does. I can't believe the votes on that answer, the OP (both here & there) has nothing to do whatsoever with the VBIDE API.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon right, I only skimmed the answers there and it was a while since I used that trust center dialog. I just checked and you're 100% right.

Comment: @rene to be fair it looks like that question was essentially hijacked with answers posting every possible reason for that error to pop up.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Ok, the number of sheets is a user setting but there is a default value already set and most users - definitely they are not power users - leave it as it is. But of course that's just a secondary topic here since I have solved it.

Comment: Oh and I'm affraid that reinstalling the Office package would not solve the problem since the problem occurs on three desktops in that company. I'm not sure about their antivirus, but I don't think it would allow to run a random macro downloaded from the net but block mine. Plus the old verision is working just fine. Anyway thanks for all suggestions.

Comment: That was @Comintern, not me (although I fully agree with that comment). FWIW it's absolutely not inconceivable that they are having the same problem on more than one machine; if the old macro wasn't edited & recompiled with Office 2019, then the fact that it works is irrelevant IMO.

Comment: One additional info: I have opened the "old version" on my Office2013, recomplied without changing anything in the code, and it was enough to make it stop working on clients desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During a meeting, when I had a chance to test it myself, it turned out that the macro was deleted by their mail server antivirus. So @rene was right to suspect it.
Thank you all for help.